# Changing WordPress Page / Post Markup

Tags: html, css, wordpress, templating

I am currently tying to convert a HTML template to a WordPress theme. We need to assign two classes to the existing `<h1>` tag, which currently has a class of `entry-title`. We would like to change the `h1` tag for: `<h4 class="heading col">`.

Can anyone tell me how to do this? Where is the code contained that creates this within WordPress?

Thanks!

Comment: Use firebug/your browsers developer tools to inspect the element and you should find all references to styling for any element on a page.

Comment: I know where the style is... I want to change the *markup*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the markup of your H1 tag inside the header.php file of your theme, some more information on the structure of wordpress themes available on the link below.
http://themetation.com/2008/07/17/how-to-create-wordpress-themes-from-scratch-part-3a/